# Building a war with Grails 2.5.3 fails with "Error WAR packaging error: Stream closed"

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline, grails-2.0

I've upgraded a Grails application from 2.3.6 to 2.5.3. I'm not trying to generate the war file with `grails war --stacktrace --verbose` (in an effort to get more information.

The last few lines of the output show:

```
| Minifying File 12 of 20 - application
| Minifying File 12 of 20 - application.
| Error WAR packaging error: Stream closed
```

I can't seem to find anything on this error, so I'm not sure if it's specific to my configuration. I was having an issue for a while where it complained about:

```
| Error Error executing script War: com.google.common.collect.Maps.immutableEnumMap(Ljava/util/Map;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
```

It seems that that was related to integrating with Atlassian's crowd product, which I was including with `com.atlassian.crowd:crowd-integration-client-rest:2.8.3`, so I updated the version of Google's "guava", and that error has gone away.

So I'm looking to figure out one of two things:

1. What can I do to build this war
2. What can I do to see more information about the error, to track it down.

**Update 1**

Because the last item before the failure is about minifying files from related to the asset-pipeline, I tried removing all files from `grails-app/assets`, and it successfully builds, so it seems to be related to that. Now trying to eliminate exactly which file is causing the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out it was related the the `asset-pipeline` plugin.

The issue was that I had `application.css` which had a reference to a non-existent css file. Once that was removed it compiled successfully.

It's too bad there wasn't a more clear error message.

Comment: I had a blank css files that was causing my stream to close.  Thanks!